# apache mod rewrite - initial URL equal rewritten URL

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I have rewrite rules and get many logs like:

> `[Thu Mar 26 11:41:00.356526 2020] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 18095] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client xy.xy.220.72:56702] xy.xt.220.72 - - [app.xyz.com/sid#7f7996613868][rid#7f79964eb0a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/app/] initial URL equal rewritten URL: /var/www/app/assets/css/management.css [IGNORING REWRITE], referer: https://app.xyz.com/management/content_page`

Things work well and I dont want to change redirect rules.
How can I get rid of this notice? As far as I understand it just means the rewrite rules did not change the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is just a *debug* notice, due to some previous testing I suspect. This should not be enabled on a production server.

You need to look for the `LogLevel` directive in the server config / virtual host. This can be set for specific modules or the server as a whole. For example, if it's only set for mod_rewrite, then you may find something like:

```
LogLevel rewrite:trace3
```

(The record from your log is a "trace1" level message, it goes up to "trace8" if you have that `LogLevel` enabled in the server config.)

Either remove / comment out this rule entirely (the default is `warn` / warning conditions) or explicitly set it to:

```
LogLevel warn
```

You'll obviously need to restart Apache after making this change.

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#loglevel